# Prove of matrix condition

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, condition-number

The matrix condition number of a matrix $A$ is defined as $\kappa(A) = \Vert A\Vert \Vert A^{-1}\Vert$. I want to show that $$\frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\Vert A\Vert = \kappa(A).$$

**Edit** There was a mistake in my original statement. It is clear that $$\frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\Vert A\Vert = \frac{\Vert A^{-1}Ax\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\Vert A\Vert\leq\Vert A^{-1}\Vert\Vert A\Vert = \kappa(A).$$
On the other hand we have $$\frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\Vert A\Vert \geq \frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert A\Vert\Vert x\Vert}\Vert A\Vert =1.$$ Now my question was whether finding $A$ and $x$ such that the bound is attained suffices to prove the desired direction of the inequality.

(Disclaimer: I asked the same question a couple of months ago. However, the given proof was incorrect, so I came up with the above idea)

Comment: I am a bit unsure what you want to show. $\frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\Vert A\Vert = \kappa(A)$ is not true for all $x$. Just take $2\times2$ diagonal matrix with different numbers on diagonal and $\Vert A\Vert = \max\{|\lambda_i|; \lambda_i \in \sigma(A)\}$

Comment: Indeed, all the $\Vert$'s made me blind... sorry. What I want to show: there is a condition number in the context of error analysis (see here for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number). My hope was that the matrix condition number is just a special case of the general definition when choosing $f(x) = Ax$. Hence I want to show that I end up with the same expressions

Answer (score 2):

The equality $\frac{\|x\|}{\|Ax\|} = \kappa(A)$ is *false*, as well as both inequalities. For $A = 2I$ ($I$ being the identity), you have $\kappa(A) = 1$ and $\|x\|/\|Ax\| = 1/2$, while for $A= I/2$, you have $\kappa(A)= 1$ and $\|x\|/\|Ax\|=2$.

Comment: Indeed, there was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. It should read $\frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\color{red}{\Vert A\Vert}$. And in fact, then your example no longer works